# Second array in different way

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Ld364rmc641 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

double A[]=new double[20];
double B;
int K,i,n;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Ld");

System.out.print("K=");

if (sc.hasNextInt())

    K = sc.nextInt();

else {
    System.out.println("input-output error");
    sc.close();
    return;
}
sc.close();
if (K==0){
    Random r = new Random();
    i=0;
    while ( i<20){
        A[i] = r.nextDouble()*20-10;
        i++;    
    }
}
else { 
    i=1;
    while(i<20){
        A[0]=0.5;
        A[i]= A[i-1]+K;
        i++;
    }
}
System.out.println("A:");
i=0;
do{
    System.out.printf("%.2f\t", A[i]);
    if (i==9)System.out.println();
    i++;
}
while (i<20);   
for (i=0; i<20; i=i+1) {
    if(i%2==0) {
enter code here
        B = A[i];
        A[i] = A[(i+1)/2];
        A[(i+1)/2] = B;
    }
    else {
        B = A[i];
        A[i]=A[i];
    A[i]=B;
}




System.out.println("\nA:");
for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%.2f\t", A[i]);
```

Needs to make the second array like this:

A0 becomes A0

A1 becomes A19

A2 becomes A1

A3 becomes A18

A4 becomes A2

A5 becomes A17

And so on.

Where is written to write code, code needs to be changed, where is penultimate for. Rest of the code is alright. Maybe someone did this task and could help me.

Comment: So even indexes from 0-18 are moved to indexes 0 to 9, and odd indexes from 1-19 are reversed to odd order from 19 to 1? Sorry but this will create an overlap on indexes 9, 7, 5, 3, 1.

Comment: Maybe i explained wrong.Firstly , make an array A from 20 digits.

Comment: Then enter   K if  K is 0 then random array if not then as I wrote in code.Secondly, print this array 10 elements in a row.Thirdly, make an array B from array A elements.Then print B array elements as I wrote below code.Fourthly, print the array B,10 elements in a row.

Answer (score 0):

This should arrange the items in the array as you specified:

```
for (i=1; i<20; i++) {
   if(i%2==0) {
      B[i] = A[i/2];
   }
   else {
      B[i] = A[20-(i+1)/2)];
   }
}
// If you want to change your original array, then just move each element in B to A:
for (i=1; i<20; i++) {
   A[i] = B[i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping . Unfortunately, nothing changes.